# It's possible to create popunder using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

It's possible to create popunder using javascript ?

I tried to search on google and every question on stackover for about `popunder`

But not get code for work good, i found only pop up code.

like this

```
<script>
var url = "yourURL.html";
window.open(url, "s", "width= 640, height= 480, left=0, top=0, resizable=yes, toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, copyhistory=no").blur();
window.focus();
</script>
```

How can i do for create popunder.

Comment: This code makes a popup and then focuses the original window causing the popup to move under the original window. This is how you make a popunder.

Comment: Sounds like a horrible thing to do

Comment: Agree with both of the above, this does seem to work as a popunder and it does sound like a bad thing to do.